# Angular 7: How to reset few checkboxes (generated dynamically using *ngFor) to it's previous state only click of a button

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox, angular7

I have a child component which consists of 3 checkboxes (generated dynamically using ngFor) and an Apply and Cancel button.

Selector tag for the child is added in the parent's template. Parent component accesses this child component using @ViewChild and calls the present() method exposed by the child component with an object as argument as below which consists of checked state of the checkboxes.

Every time when modal is displayed, present() method is getting called. For the first time, UI/checkboxes is getting updated/checked as the values sent by parent. But, in the subsequent calls to present(), even though options.checked value is getting updated as expected in the ts file, this is not getting reflected in the UI. Every time the modal is displayed, I want checkbox to be checked or unchecked based on the value sent by the parent in present() method. Need help. Thanks in advance

parent.component.ts:

```
@ViewChild(childModalComponent) childModalComponent: ChildModalComponent;

onBtnClick() {
 this.childModalComponent.present({
  checkbox1: true,
  checkbox2: false,
  checkbox3: false
 });
}
```

parent.component.html:

```
<feature-child-modal></feature-child-modal>
```

child.component.ts:

```
 @ViewChild('childModal') childModal: ElementRef;

 ngOnInit() {
    this.options = [
     {
       label: 'label1',
       value: 'value1',
       checked: false,
     },
     {
       label: 'label2',
       value: 'value2',
       checked: false,
     },
     {
       label: 'label3',
       value: 'value3',
       checked: false,
     },
  ];
 }

present(optionsState: CompressTransactionType) {
  this.options.forEach(item => {
    if(item.value == "value1"){
      item.checked = optionsState.checkbox1;
    }

    if(item.value == "value2"){
      item.checked = optionsState.checkbox2;
    }

    if(item.value == "value3"){
      item.checked = optionsState.checkbox3;
    }
  });

  this.childModal.nativeElement.present();
}

dismiss() {
  this.childModal.nativeElement.dismiss();
}
```

child.component.html:

```
    <div *ngFor="let option of options">
      <input
          type="checkbox"
          [value]="option.value"
          (change)="onOptionsSelectChanged($event)"
          [checked]="option.checked" />
    </div>
```

Comment: firstly use '===' and then check if you code is infact going to the if block or not

Comment: @ploofah, Yes, it is going inside the if block and value is getting set as expected. But it is not getting reflected in UI

Comment: please check the attribute called label in checkbox... dont think there is one for checkbox

Comment: @NithinP.H label is working fine. In my code, I am using a customized component so it is working.

Answer (score 0):

try passing the array object here `option` instead of `$event`. Have a look in this url..

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wifdeg

Comment: My issue is not with the click event, I am facing issue in present() method. present method is called in Parent component and sends an argument with values for checkboxes. Based on this value sent by the parent component, child components checkboxes needs to be checked/unchecked every time the child modal component is presented.

Comment: sorry for getting the requirement wrong... please check the url now